# how to get the html text length without set it to a textfield?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

in actionscript ,i didn't find a direct way to get the actually string's length of a html text.here's how i get things work

```
var myText:String = "<p>This is <b>some</b> content to <i>render</i> as <u>HTML</u> text.</p>"; 
myTextBox.htmlText = myText;
trace(myTextBox.length);
```

deal with large content of html text would be a performance problem.

is there a way i can get the length while i don't have to pass it to a text device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to extract the text from xml:

1. For the `xHTML` the best way is to parse it to XML and extract all text nodes
2. For all types of text you can try `RegExp` that matches text that is not part of a HTML tag (http://regexr.com?363li)

   ```
   var s:String = "<p>This is <b>some</b> content to <i>render</i> as <u>HTML</u> text.</p>";

   //by TextField
   var tf:TextField = new TextField();
   tf.htmlText = s;
   trace(tf.text);
   trace(tf.length);

   //well-formed XML
   XML.ignoreWhitespace = false;
   var x:XML = new XML(s);

   var t:String = "";
   var list:XMLList = x..*;
   for each(var node:XML in list)
       if(node.nodeKind() == "text")
           t += node;

   trace(t);
   trace(t.length);

   //by RegExp (non wel formed XML)
   var match:Array = s.match(/(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)/gs);
   s = match.join("");
   trace(t);
   trace(t.length);
   ```

output:

```
22528
21  ms
22528
35  ms
22528
20  ms
```

But all these techniques seems to be almost equals by performance, as you can see for the string with 22k chars all methods runs with almost the same result 20-30 ms, but anyway you can try both methods for your input.

Comment: So you have to use RegExp. I updated my answer with regexp that matches all text within any tag.

Comment: 22k is too less ,try 1 MB, you'll see the difference

Comment: Yes, it seems after some size TextField gets lags, I tryed 720k chars and gets following results: 6825  ms (TextField), 269  ms (XML), 597  ms (RegExp)